# UITextField - Not sending to firebase if textfield contains certain words

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, uitextfield

im making a Chat app for kids, i have already setup everything for the users to send messages to eachother (and it gets stored in firebase).

However i dont want the kids to send mean words to eachother (like for example "idiot", or "butthead").

If the texfield contains one of the words that i have written in code, i want the viewcontroller to dismiss when they click send , and not send it to firebase.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: You could let the post happen and then censor it, using cloud functions to "Sanitize" the post. Google has a youtube channel that has a tutorial for this question. Go to YouTube and find the firebase channel and watch the cloud functions playlist. You'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
let wordsToCensor = ["idiot","butthead"...] // make them all lowercased for comparison
let wordsToCompare = postTextField.text.lowercased()
for word in wordsToCensor {
    if wordsToCompare.range(of:word) {
        // do cancel post here
    }
}
```